# Android device not showing up in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, usb, drivers

I've just bought a new Android phone to develop with - its a Vodafone 785 (Smart mini).

I have followed all the instructions, i.e. allow usb debugging/ non market apks etc, however the device is not showing up in eclipse, nor is it showing up if I use the 'adb device' command.

I'm guessing it may be the drivers. Are the drivers needed specific to each phone? If so does anybody know where I may be able to find them, if they have had problems like this before/used this phone for development. Thanks a lot!

Comment: try this -->http://www.updatestar.com/topic/vodafone%20785

Answer (score 1):

First of all, according to the Google Android device documentation, we need to have a Windows USB driver for ADB (Android Debug Bridge).  ADB is a method for communicating with Android devices at a level in which development and debugging is possible.
Try this tutorial:-

http://developandroid.blogopogo.com/tag/adb-driver-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Download All MTK USB Driver, See if that works and Install the universal android driver.

Answer (score 0):

Ok for anyone else who has this problem with this phone, you need the alcatel usb driver, found here: http://hexamob.com/driversen/driversen-driversen/download-android-usb-drivers-for-alcatel/